# mysql database empty after phpmyadmin upload

Tags: mysql, import

This is probably a silly question, but I just can't think of what's wrong here.

I create a new database in MySql databases, I create a user for that database, all works fine.
Then I jump into phpmyadmin, select the empty database on the left and import the .gz file.

The problem is, when I go back to MySql databases, the database shows as 0.00 MB.

What the heck? I imported it, it's sitting there.

Comment: Don't mess up *Data* and *Structure*. The data might be 0 Byte (because it's empty), that's my guess

Comment: Oh there's data in it for sure.

Comment: Oh. Did you check *export/import data AND structure* ? What's in the SQL files in the GZ archieve?

Comment: It's a WordPress database, I exported it locally then imported the .gz file. I've never had this problem before.

Comment: You got the message the import was successfully imported in phpmyadmin?

Comment: Yup. "Import has been successfully finished, 1992 queries executed. (ownsite.sql.gz)"

Comment: did you try running some select queries to see whether there's data?

Comment: I'm not much of a database guy, so no. But I can see there's data in phpmyadmin under the 'size', so there's definitely stuff there.

Comment: Did you already try to logout of phpmyadmin / close browser and login again? Maybe you can post some screenshots of phpmyadmin?

Comment: Use phpmyadmin to browse the contents of one of your tables; wp_posts is probably a good one to look at.  That many queries, no failures? data is surely loaded.

Comment: wp_posts has 1.6MB of data in it. No failures.

Comment: It appears to have been an issue with WHM. Fixed it now. Will update answer later when i fix my other issues.